# Set attribute disabled for checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

i want to show the checkbox disabled when either of the values are coming, but it is working only for one value.

```
<ui:inputCheckbox value="{!product.productSelection}" disabled="{! 
 or(product.orderLineStatus == 'Cancelled', product.orderLineStatus == 
 'Rejected',product.orderLineStatus == 'Scheduled to Ship')}"/>
```

Comment: The "or" function only supports 2 parameters last I checked; you might need to do something like `or(.., or(.., ..))`. Could you try that?

Comment: like @sfdcfox you can use 
`<ui:inputCheckbox value="{!product.productSelection}" disabled="{!or(product.orderLineStatus == 'Cancelled', or(product.orderLineStatus == 
 'Rejected',or(product.orderLineStatus == 'Scheduled to Ship')))}"/>` 
otherwise you can use ternary operator to that stuff

`<ui:inputCheckbox value="{!product.productSelection}" disabled="{!(product.orderLineStatus == 'Cancelled'?true: product.orderLineStatus == 
 'Rejected'?true:product.orderLineStatus == 'Scheduled to Ship'?true:false)}"/>`

Comment: @sfdcfox That's odd. At least in formulas `OR` supports indefinite arguments.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes, lightning expressions are meant to support unlimited arguments, but haven't thus far. I suspect we'll get it sooner or later (hoping for sooner).